# Does spring-data-couchbase support Field Level Encryption with @EncryptField annotation?

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to persist/retrieve a Document in couchbase with an encrypted field via the CrudRepository or the CouchbaseTemplate

Starting from the example in the [devguide of couchbase](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/devguide-examples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/couchbase/devguide/FieldEncryptionAES.java) i've added the crypto provider in my spring configuration like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = { "com.example.demo.db" })
public class MyCouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCouchbaseConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
        return Arrays.asList("localhost", "127.0.0.1");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketName() {
        return "TEST";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getUsername() {
        return "user";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketPassword() {
        return "p4$$w0rd";
    }

    @Override
    public String typeKey() {
        return MappingCouchbaseConverter.TYPEKEY_SYNCGATEWAY_COMPATIBLE;
    }

    @Override
    protected CouchbaseEnvironment getEnvironment() {
        try {
            JceksKeyStoreProvider kp = new JceksKeyStoreProvider("secret");
            kp.publicKeyName("mypublickey");
            kp.storeKey("mypublickey", "!mysecretkey#9^5usdk39d&dlf)03sL".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            kp.signingKeyName("HMACsecret");
            kp.storeKey("HMACsecret", "myauthpassword".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            AES256CryptoProvider aes256CryptoProvider = new AES256CryptoProvider(kp);
            CryptoManager cryptoManager = new CryptoManager();
            cryptoManager.registerProvider("MyAESProvider", aes256CryptoProvider);
            return DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder().cryptoManager(cryptoManager).build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

this is the document to persist

```
@Document
public class Person {

    @Id
    public String id;

    @EncryptedField(provider = "MyAESProvider")
    public String password;

    //The rest will be transported and stored unencrypted
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String userName;
    public int age;
}
```

and this is the repository

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

}
```

call to (autowired)

```
personRepository.save(person);
```

or

```
couchbaseTemplate.insert(person);
```

will store the object in clear

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "password": "password",
  "javaClass": "com.example.demo.db.Person",
  "userName": "jdoe",
  "age": 20
}
```

while this code (from the example but with my spring configuration)

```
Bucket bucket = couchConfig.couchbaseClient();
EntityDocument<Person> document = EntityDocument.create(person);
bucket.repository().upsert(document);
EntityDocument<Person> stored = bucket.repository().get(person.id, Person.class);
System.out.println("Password: " + stored.content().password);
```

store this object

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "__crypt_password": {
    "sig": "h1QS9JacNxTBrep4TEkZj/N7EsV3zJQ6vXmYtzADdG8=",
    "ciphertext": "G3rAivta7NOnLP5Qb1nEfw==",
    "alg": "AES-256-HMAC-SHA256",
    "iv": "cGjOOgA4M+wg4WcM0pHAFw==",
    "kid": "mypublickey"
  },
  "userName": "jdoe",
  "age": 20
}
```

It seems to me that Spring Data Couchbase use the `Bucket` interface (that ignore annotations on the document) instead of the `Bucket.repository()` (that takes the FLE into account instead).

So finally the question is: "How can I use spring Spring Data Couchbase `Repository` or `CouchbaseTemplate` to store `@EncryptedField` of a `@Document` with the FLE feature of Couchbase?"

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem right now but unfortunately, I found it's a future improvement in the SpringDataCouchbase team Jira board.

https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATACOUCH/issues/DATACOUCH-455?filter=allopenissuess.

So, no much to do for now. Did you find a better approach than using the `bucket.repository().upsert(document);` @Domenico U.?

Comment: That Jira is mine :) .. however we have switched to mongoDB for other reasons..

Comment: :-).... @DomenicoU. Actually I had to implement a basic encryption functionality using Spring AOP and creating my own annotation to mark fields I want to encrypt. It's pretty basic but it works as expected without the modifications required by couchbase SDK.